# Syntax of \tikzmath{function....?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

What is wrong with the syntax of the two `\tikzmath` function definitions function here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{function f(\x) { return sin(\x);
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    

  \tikzmath{function g(\x) { return cos(\x);
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Please be gentle: I'm still a rank newbie with `TikZ`!)

Comment: It seems there are more opening `{` than closing `}`...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Please, please be more helpful by showing me what the correct syntax is in both places.

Comment: You write `\tikzmath{ function g(\x) { return cos(\x); };`, so you never close the first `{`. You should rather type `\tikzmath{ function g(\x) { return cos(\x); }; }` and similarly for the other function.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: got it, thanks!  (My ignorance was not over matching parentheses but rather where semicolons did or did not go. And all the examples I found in the TikZ manual and online were much more complicated.)

Comment: It seems that every command inside `\tikzmath` should be ended with a semicolon. So, it should be `function x(\y) { ... };` as well as `return ... ;`. But I have to admit, it was rather a guess for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little example usage. Note that I use `\tikzmath` between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, not in the preamble.

About the placement of semi columns: the manual states that *every (tikzmath) statement should end with a semi-colon*.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
    function f(\x) { 
        return sin(\x);
        };
    real \f;
    \f = f(90);
    print \f;
    print \newline; % new line; the next line begins with no indent
    print f(45); % prints "f(45)" verbatim
    % No blank line allowed
    print \par; % new paragraph; the next line begins with an indent
    \f = f(-45);
    print \f;
}

Foo

\begin{tikzpicture}    

\tikzmath{
    function g(\x) {
        return cos(\x);
        };
    real \g;
    \g = g(180);
    };
\node at (0,0) {\g}; % use \g outside of \tikzmath, in a tikz node 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** more about what is a statement.

According to the pgf/Ti*k*Z manual, there are different types of statements in a `\tikzmath` command:

- Assignment (e.g. `\a = 3 + 4;` or `let \x = 2*3;`)
- "Type-declaration" (`int \i;`, `real \z;` or `coordinate \c;`)
- iterations (e.g. `for \n in {1,...,5} {⟨other statements⟩};`)
- conditionals (e.g. `if ⟨condition⟩ then ⟨statements⟩ else ⟨statements⟩;`)
- function declaration (e.g. `function product(\x,\y) {return \x*\y;};`, note that here `return \x*\y;` is also a statement, and the second `;` in the first code is for the function declaration statement)

If a statement begins with a brace `{`, the closing brace `}` must be followed by a semi-column.

Here I take an exemple from the pgf/Ti*k*Z manual, with additional comments (section 58.7 *Executing Code Outside the Parser*, page 708 in the current manual):

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2); % a common `\draw` TikZ command,
                               % which ends with a ";"
\tikzmath{ % begin of the \tikzmath command. Not a statemnt
  coordinate \c;               % a statement
  for \x in {0,10,...,360} {   % begin of a statement, no ";" here
    \c = (1.5cm, 1cm) + (\x:1cm and 0.5cm); % a statement inside
                                            % the for statement
    { \fill (\c) circle [radius=1pt]; }; % a second statement
                                         % inside the for statement.
                                         % In it, a common TikZ command
                                         % (`\draw`) which ends as usual
                                         % by a semi-column.
  }; % the end of the for statement. Ended by a semi-column
} % end of \tikzmath command. It's not a statement
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the Tikz `\draw` command inside the `\tikzmath` is surrounded by braces, so after the `;` for the end of `\draw`, there is also a `;` after the closing brace.

Comment: My confusion remains as to what exactly constitutes a tikzmath "statement."

Comment: @murray I have added more explanations. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, very helpful; thank you.

Comment: In your own example, the thing that confuses me is why a semicolon is needed after `return sin(\x)`, given that that phrase is inside braces; I would think that the closing brace is the end of the "command" and hence would be the sole place within that `function` constructions that a semicolon terminator is required. Can you explain further?

Comment: @murray, see the remark in the text in my 5th bullet: `return \x*\y;` is also a statement. See the manual, it's explicitly stated. Page 703: *This command process a series of ⟨statements⟩ which can represent assignments, **function definitions**, conditional evaluation, and iterations.*. Page 707, section 58.6 (Declaring Functions), the second point: **`return ⟨expression⟩;`**. It's a statement for `\tikzmath`.

Comment: @murrau, note that if the `⟨expression⟩` is a conditional, it will be surrounded by braces and also ends by a semi-column inside the return statement. E.g. `return {if ⟨condition⟩ then ⟨statements⟩ else ⟨statements⟩;};`. This can gives `return {if \k>1 then {let \c = orange;} else {let \c = blue;};};`.